# may a linux client do prerouting with iptables

Tags: iptables, forwarding

In our network I have 3 clients: A, B and C (connected to the same router).
I tried to redirect the traffic that arrive to B on port `4440` to C on port `4441` using iptables-legacy

1. simulating port listener on B: I typed `nc -l 4440`
2. simulating port listener on C: I typed `nc -l 4441`
3. on B: `bog@bog-desktop:~$ sudo iptables-legacy -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 4440 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.14:4441`

then from A i tried to telnet to B on port 4440:
`telnet 192.168.1.B 4440` (I use B instead of the number just to make it easier) and after a while I get the message `Connection timed out`.

Then I print again my chains:

```
bog@bog-desktop:~$ sudo iptables-legacy -L -v --line-numbers -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 18 packets, 5949 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        2   120 DNAT       tcp  --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4440 to:192.168.1.14:4441

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 18 packets, 5949 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7 packets, 1941 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 9 packets, 2061 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

and I realize that a couple of pkgs ave arrived to the `PREROUTING` chain but haven't received them on the C machine.

But `telnet 192.168.1.C 4441` works just fine
PS, I also enabled forwarding on B with `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

I couldn't solve my problem with any of articles I have found online.

Comment: doesn't work because replies from C skip B. A sees packets from C it doesn't know about.

Comment: Pardon, I didn't understand.

Comment: Can't tell it better than what I wrote. You assume C didn't receive anything. The only way to validate this hypothesis is to run tcpdump on C and double check.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try.